# What is the correct way to package an enterprise application

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss7.x

Assume your application consists only of one war file. My understanding is, that any third party library I need, and I am allowed to provide, I will include in my war, in WEB-INF/lib.

Today I came across someone who told me some details about JBoss 7 and their concept of modules, suggesting that an application should not deliver any third party library...but rather request the library in the correct version from the application server.

I am still more the type of guy who likes to deliver a full package, w/o any dependencies another user has to make sure, they are fullfilled. **Now, long story short....is there a "Java EE standard" answer, how to cope with third party libraries in enterprise applications?'**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [Java EE 6 Tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnadx.html#indexterm-189):

> The document root contains a subdirectory named WEB-INF, which can contain the following files and directories:
>
> classes: A directory that contains server-side classes: servlets, enterprise bean class files, utility classes, and JavaBeans components
>
> tags: A directory that contains tag files, which are implementations of tag libraries
>
> lib: A directory that contains JAR files that contain enterprise beans, and JAR archives of libraries called by server-side classes
>
> Deployment descriptors, such as web.xml (the web application deployment descriptor) and ejb-jar.xml (an EJB deployment descriptor)

So /WEB-INF/lib is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The "standard" answer depends on whether or not your Java EE app server supports the OSGi or [JSR-277](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=277) standard.

[JBOSS version 7](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossOSGi) does support OSGi; earlier versions might not.

So it's really two answers: one for pre-OSGi servers ("put JARs in WEB-INF/lib for your app or the server /lib") and post-OSGi ("use OSGi").

Comment: Are you saying that post-OSGi servers do not support putting libraries in WEB-INF/lib?